# Javascript Regular Expression manipulation

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string like below

```
string TagName = "Synergy-SunOptics-545-888-LLA     Replacement" ;
```

On this, I am using a regular expression like below.

```
TagName =TagName.replace(/\d{3}-\d{3}-[A-Z]{3}\s([\w\s]*)$/,a+"-"+b+"-"+c+" $1");
```

What it does is, this regular expression replaces the 3 numeric values i.e (545-888) with the numeric values I provide, but this works only if I provide exactly 3 numeric values for each numeric set..ie..

It works:

```
"Synergy-SunOptics-676-454-LLA     Replacement"
```

Its not working:

```
"Synergy-SunOptics-54-8884-LLA     Replacement"
```

So,  I need that this regular expression should work with any no. of numeric values provided..  for eg.. "1111-1111" or  "11-1111" or "1-1111" or "1111-111" etc..

Comment: Why not `\d+` instead of `\d{3}` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use the `+` quantifier in place of the `{3}` quantifier. `+` matches one or more occurrences. Whereas `{3}` specifies exactly three occurrences.

Like so:

```
TagName =TagName.replace(/\d+-\d+-[A-Z]{3}\s([\w\s]*)$/,a+"-"+b+"-"+c+" $1");
```

Or alternatively, if you need to match a specific range of occurrences, you can use a range quantifier: `{1,8}` would match 1 to 8 occurences, `{6, 15}` would match 6 to 15 occurrences etc.

See the quantifier section at this site for more information on JavaScript flavored regex quantifiers [javascript regex cheat sheet](https://www.debuggex.com/cheatsheet/regex/javascript)

Comment: @JonM..Thanks for you quick help.. I used like this now.. but it doesn't work TagName =TagName.replace(/\d{+}-\d{+}-[A-Z]{3}\s([\w\s]*)$/,a+"-"+b+"-"+c+" $1");

Comment: remove the curly braces

Answer (score 0):

```
TagName =TagName.replace(/\d+-\d+-[A-Z]{3}\s([\w\s]*)$/,a+"-"+b+"-"+c+" $1");
```